# Reg - Matlab Simulink 3D Simulation Acceleration using GPU

Tags: matlab, gpu, simulink, unreal-engine4

*Selected MEX compiler 'mingw64-g++' is not supported for GPU code generation.*
I appreciate if someone could help me on this

I tried to accelerate my 3D vehicle simulation using Unreal through simulink but it haven't worked included the picture for reference

[image]

Comment: The error is clear .. you don't understand english ?

Comment: You will have to use a msvc2017 or msvc2019 for this, which i think you should have if you are compiling unreal engine

Comment: Thank you, I have those installed could you direct me how should i proceed further

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html